# C# export to excel leading zeros

Tags: c#

I have an export to excel function but, how do you keep excel from suppressing leading zeros when exporting to excel? I have the following code that applies a style but its not working...any ideas?

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
     "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        //Apply text style to each Row
        GridView1.Rows[i].Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
    }
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

    //style to format numbers to string
    string style = @"<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
    Response.Write(style);
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

Comment: are you sending it as a string or an int?

Comment: string style = @"<style> .text { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Down and dirty, send the value as a string with a `'` (single quote) at the start.

Comment: I tried that but the single quote appears on the excel sheet?

Comment: Thank you sir. Single quote at the start did it.

Answer (score 0):

Add "\t" before your string. It'll make the string seem in a new tab.